# Self-made Matter device can't be commissioned by Google Home

Tags: iot, google-smart-home, matter-iot-standard

I'm building a Matter light bulb. My light can be commissioned by Apple Home app, with Apple TV as home hub; and I can control it on-off or dimming.
But the problem is my light can't be commissioned by Google Home app, with Google Nest as hub.

The error says something about my phone wasn't connecting to WiFi, but actually it did connect fine. And everything else are setup correctly, I think.
So if any encounter the problem like that? And what can I do to overcome it.
Here's my checklist before commissions:
On my phone:

- Android: 8.1.0.
- Developer Options: turned on.
- USB Debugging: turned on.
- Google Play Services: com.google.android.gms.home [v225014000], com.google.android.gms.threadnetwork [v225014000]
  On my hub:
- Hub type: Google Nest Hub 2nd gen
- Chromecast firmware version: 1.56.324896
  On my light:
- Vendor ID: 0xFFF1 (as in default CHIPDeviceConfig.h)
  Developer Project: created
  [My screenshot of Developer Project created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoSfD.jpg)
  My CHIPDeviceConfig.h: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x_5NDoKkxW1Un_8NO3biwUlYF5BqCe-Z/view?usp=sharing
  My log of commissioning: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qMMCxS2dZWkbZNYRENJ7wiZrTC0UTxVL/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I had a similar problem with Google. I was advised to create a completely new test user and a developer project. I created a new user on my phone and re-registered the Net Hub to it as well. This worked.

Comment: Could you share your phone logcat for phone ? Also, could you try executing the following two grep commands and share the logs 
              grep "MatterCommissioner" $phonelog
              grep "SetupDevice" $phonelog | grep -A 40 "Commissioning failed"

Answer (score 0):

The matter devices under active development would be using test VID/PID combination which is possible to commission on Google Ecosystem today. You will need to create a project on Google Home console, register the VID/PID and use the account login to the console for commissioning the device on Google Home App.

The instructions on how to setup up a pre-production can be found in [get started](https://developers.home.google.com/matter/get-started) guide in the developer documentation.

Comment: One more reason not to invest in the Google ecosystem.